# Angular 4/5 Datatable suggestions (CDKTable)

Tags: angular, html-table, visualization, css-tables

I have recently been working on a project and I have a running backend and all communication between my angular app and backend is working fluently.

I get data(wearables) from my backend which is an array with all necessary data. And what I want to do is to display each element of this array as a row in a table. To give u guys a bit of a visualization i have made the following prototype.[The in red marked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHdC6.png)

I have looked into a few packages and components to generate tables in Angular, however all of these table do not support the styling I want. They all show a basic table template and styling. So my question is what do you guys advice me to use or what should I do to realise my prototype in my application.

P.S: I have alreaady tried different packages and I got this result with the CDKTable [CDKTable try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzeBx.jpg). However this module doesnt support sorting nor filtering the way I want. And also the header is part of the table(see scrollbar length).

Comment: have you tried ngx-datatable?

Comment: Sorry I was very busy last week, yes i will have a look at  ngx-datatable thanks  for the help!